# Passing parameters to dataflow task

Tags: ssis

Can I do something like this inside the sql command for a dataflow task?
When I click on the parameters button, I get an error complaining about parameters not being able to be extracted from the query.

```
    DECLARE @DbId INT, @ServerKey INT
    DECLARE @DbName VARCHAR(100)
    SELECT @DbId = ?, @ServerKey = ?

    SET @DbName = DB_NAME(@DbId)

    SET NOCOUNT ON
...
```

Comment: I would think it could be done.   How did you map the ssis parameters to the placeholders in the query?

Comment: I couldnt get that far.  Ive since decided to take a different approach.  Im putting the sql query in a file, reading that file into a string and then doing a string replace in a script task.  That way my data flow can use a command from a variable.  At least thats the idea at the moment.